# Automated installation of any program's setup wizard using powershell/cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, administration

I've got a major issue automating the installation of a program w/o user interference. I have a setup wizard, but I can't wrap up my head about finding the parameters to input in cmd or powershell so it install the program silently, tried 
`start-process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\install.exe' -ArgumentList '/S' -wait`
it will only run the wizard. 
The question is - is there any way so I can put in the parameters to the wizard, or extract the parameters list from wizard file, so I can automate the installation of the program.

Comment: Can use `Invoke-Expression "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\install.exe /S"`

Comment: setup.exe is not a command, won't work, tried it

Comment: `& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Install.exe' /S`. (Note the call operator, `&`, the quotes around the file name, and the parameter is separate.) See the article [Running Executables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) for more information.

Comment: thank you! will definately try this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way. Few ways actually.

- Use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/): `cinst notepadplusplus`. People already maintain huge number of packages and this way you contribute to the community. By creating choco package you will actually get to know all the steps to automate any install.
- To find out silent args use `usff` (Universal Silent Switch FInder): `cinst usff`.
- To find wizard params (customizations) use for instance insted: `cinst insted`. Some choco packages allow you to customize this via parameters - for instance [yed](https://chocolatey.org/packages/yed) has parameter that allows you to create desktop shortcut.
- You can examine source code of the package to see how it is installed in automated fashion if you don't want (or can't) use chocolatey.

If you want old fashion just run:

```
 .\installer.exe /S
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply! But I'm still in search of cmd or powershell approach to do that

Comment: That IS powershell approach. Anyway, see my edited answer.

Comment: just tried the old fashion: it runs the wizard so I have to choose everything manually, I'd like to do it automatically. Currently checking out Chocolately, the program I need to install is not to be used publicly, so I'm not sure if I can do that

Comment: Do you want notepad++ or something else ? Every tool has its own automation so if you wanted to learn via npp you wont do much. The command I posted above on my system installs it. `/S` is all you need to silent install in this case. It shouldn't give you the UI.

Comment: As for choco, yes, you can use it for private things. Even on premise.

Comment: something else, a corporate program. Is there a way to get the parameters of installation or *.exe file? Or the best way will be to contact the dev team who wrote it?

Comment: You have to use the tools I mentioned. Contacting developers or searching their forum is an option too.

Comment: thank you very much for the expertise, have a great day!

Comment: No problem. Good luck. You can ask on chocolatey forum for help too.